# How to retrieve the last N elements from a LinkedHashMap

Tags: java

I have a `LinkedHashMap` that is:

```
Map<String, Double> indDistance = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
```

That I sort it as:

```
Map<String, Double> sortedInds = 
                indDistance.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

How can I retrieve the last N elements from `sortedInds`?

Comment: Do you mean the last N entries that were added to the `Map` ?

Comment: Use .size() and .get(index)

Comment: @Abra Assume the map has 10 elements, after sorting it I want to get the last 3 elements (element 8, 9, and 10).

Comment: @LucaJung I don't see method `get(index)` in class [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: @Abra Sorry, forgot that you first copy the Map to a list.

Comment: Maybe reverse the sort and get the first N elements?

Comment: @Abra Can you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

A `Comparator` that determines whether the first `Double` is larger than the second...

```java
public class ReverseDoubleComparator implements java.util.Comparator<Double> {
    public int compare(Double d1, Double d2) {
        return (d1.compareTo(d2)) * (-1);
    }
}
```

Now use this `Comparator` in `sorted()` method, i.e.

```java
Map<String, Double> sortedInds = 
                indDistance.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Entry.comparingByValue(new ReverseDoubleComparator()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: `Comparator.reverseOrder()` does the same thing as your custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using `sortedInds` for anything else other than getting the last `n` elements, you could replace collecting it to a `Map` with returning the last `n` elements as a `List`:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> sortedInds = indDistance.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .limit(n)
        .toList();
```

This sorts the `Map` in reverse order by value, limits the results just the first `n` elements, then returns the resulting `Entry` values as a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get the last n elements of an existing `LinkedHashMap` as a `List<Entry>`:

```java
int n = 3;

List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> lastN = sortedInds.entrySet().stream()
        .skip(sortedInds.size() - n)
        .toList();
```